# Not able to read text from webpage using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

i am not able to read the email id from the webpage below :

URL : https://targetstudy.com/university/2/acharya-ng-ranga-agricultural-university/

Here is my code

```
driver.navigate().to(URL);
String Email = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="site-canvas"]/div[6]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/img")).getText();
System.out.println(Email);
```

Comment: email id is in image file. so you cant get as text .

Comment: the email is in text file if u want u can get url of the email image

Comment: @VelGuru :
Yes, i know, that this is an image , i want to know how can i get the text from it.
is there any solution??

Thanks

Comment: @bhupathituraga : Thanks for reply, but i want to know how can i get the text from it...

Answer (score 0):

Selenium alone can't help you in this case, though your binding language would help you.

You need Java Tesseract API.

**Code** for extracting text :

```
 public String getImgText(String imageLocation) {
      ITesseract instance = new Tesseract();
      try 
      {
         String imgText = instance.doOCR(new File(imageLocation));
         return imgText;
      } 
      catch (TesseractException e) 
      {
         e.getMessage();
         return "Error while reading image";
      }
   }
```

If you are using maven for your Project, just add this dependency :

```
<dependency> 
 <groupId>net.sourceforge.tess4j</groupId> 
 <artifactId>tess4j</artifactId> 
 <version>3.2.1</version> 
</dependency>
```

More Reference :  [Extracting text from Image](https://dzone.com/articles/extracting-text-from-image-converting-image-text)

Comment: :- Thanks for reply, but it did not work for me , error appears .
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unsupported image format. May need to install JAI Image I/O package.
https://java.net/projects/jai-imageio/